# How to solve a equation with special conditions?

Tags: diophantine-equations, functional-equations

I have this equation: $z = 11n + 13m$

Conditions: $z < 2015$

$z$, $n$ and $m$ must be natural numbers ($>0$).

How many options are possible for $z$?

Comment: Welcome to math stackexchange.  What have you thought about or tried?  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: you can use a computer program to find all values of $n,m$

Comment: I used the HP-15c for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 11n + 13m ≤ 2014; m, n natural with nm > 0. 
2014 – 11 = 2003 and 2003/13 = 154 + 1/13. Then for n = 1, 2, 3, 4,……, 154 there are respectively the solutions 
(1, x) with 1 ≤ x ≤ 154;(2, x) with 1≤ x ≤ 153;......(153, x) with x = 1 and 2;
(154, x) with x = 1.

Then this gives 154x155/2 = 11 935 solutions.
On the other hand, m can range from 1-154 only because  13x155 = 2015 and this gives the solutions
(x, 1) with 1 ≤ x ≤ 154; (x, 2) with 1≤ x ≤ 153; ………, (x,153) with x = 1 and 2 and (x, 154) with x = 1.
We have to note carefully that all the solutions of the first group are repeated in the second group. Consequently there are 11 935 – X possible values for z, where X is the number of eventual solutions of the diophantine equation 11x +13y = 11z + 13w with (x, y) ≠ (z, w) in the allowed domain. We need to solve this equation. I allow myself to leave this final problem to other citizens who want to address the problem posted by linuscl.

Comment: I think there can't be more values then 2015...

Comment: Maybe because the indicated diophantine equation  HAS SOLUTIONS so if you are okey X is big.

Comment: I solved it with my calculator (loop programming): There are 335 options for _z_. There is only one problem: How to find overlaps?

Comment: If there are exactly 335 options for your z then X = 11935 - 335. This is too many I guess. Consequently there should be more options for z

Comment: Yes, I see. Maybe there is bug in my program. :( I'll try it again. But are there any overlaps (if I can calculate one number with two calculuses)?

Comment: I suggest you try your problem first with the condition z < 100 or less so you can  do directly your question